# Feature request - Change color of block quote

Tags: feature-request, design, css

I'd like to request that the color of block quotes gets changed from a light gray to a light yellow (like SO, AE)

As it is now, it's very hard to see the difference between a block quote and a code block.

My answer to this post is a perfect example: [Customize ubuntu (change logo and startup app)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772678/customize-ubuntu-change-logo-and-startup-app/772717#772717)

**Edit to address dupe marking:**

Yes, it is a duplicate, but nothing came of it. So I'm bringing it up again.